# how to save xml data in one file

Tags: php, xml

I am begginer in the php part so please help me out.This is my php script which help to generate the XML file

```
<?php

   mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
   mysql_select_db('dcu');


   $sql = "SELECT meterId FROM meter";
   $res = mysql_query($sql);
   $xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('meteries');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {


   $xml->startElement("meterId");
   $xml->writeRaw($row['meterId']);
   $xml->endElement();

    }

$xml->endElement();


   header('Content-type: text/xml');
   $xml->flush();
   ?>
   After running this php script i got this xml file in my terminal as well as in browser

  <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <cemeteries>
 <meterId>1</meterId>
 <meterId>2</meterId>
</cemeteries>
```

My question was how to save this generated xml in some other xml file

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save it on the server you can do like this:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
mysql_select_db('dcu');

$sql = "SELECT meterId FROM meter";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('meteries');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $xml->startElement("meterId");
    $xml->writeRaw($row['meterId']);
    $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

$content = $xml->flush();

$fp = fopen('data.xml', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $content;
```

On fopen() in mode 'w' if the file does not exist PHP will attempt to create it. Be sure PHP has sufficient rights to write.

Comment: after doing changes the file is created but in that file nothing is their ans also when i am try to run on browser it got this error XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://localhost/third.php
Line Number 6, Column 1:

Comment: It seems the flush() method doesn't return the contents of the xml file when using openURI(), instead it returns the number of written bytes. When you use openMemory() it should return the xml contents. I have adjusted my answer to fit the needs. Good luck!